# Trying to pass the JSONArray object but it is getting converted to String

Tags: java, json, gson, android

Hello i am trying to remove the double quotes around this String(Although this is JsonArray object i am creating in Java but this is giving out this " " which i want to omit )

```
"secretKey":"[\"121212\",\"32234324\"]"
```

What i want is this

```
"secretKey" : ["121212","32234324"]
```

And in my JsonAdapter(Implementing the TypeAdapter) `reader.beginArray()` throws following exception

```
IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 179 path $.secretKey
```

Help me folks i am stuck since last 2 days.

Here is some code if you all can understand actually i am trying to make an object through makeiteasy object builder .

```
    public class ApplicationWrapperMaker {
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, Long> id = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, User> createdBy = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, Integer> updatedBy = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, Timestamp> createdAt = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, String> packageName = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, Integer> otpExpiry = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, Integer> otpLength = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, Integer> requestPerIp = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, String> senderId = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, String> key = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, String> name = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, String> signature = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, ApplicationType> type = newProperty();
    public static final Property<ApplicationWrapper, JSONArray> secretKey = newProperty();

    public static final Instantiator<ApplicationWrapper> ApplicationWrapper = lookup -> {
        ApplicationWrapper applicationWrapper  = new ApplicationWrapper();
//        List<String> secKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
//        secKeys.add("some-sec-key");
//        secKeys.add("some-other-sec-key");
        applicationWrapper.setPackageName(lookup.valueOf(packageName, "some.package.name"));
        applicationWrapper.setOtpExpiry(lookup.valueOf(otpExpiry, (Integer) null));
        applicationWrapper.setKey(lookup.valueOf(key, "some-application-key"));
        applicationWrapper.setName(lookup.valueOf(name, "someApplicationName"));
        applicationWrapper.setSenderId(lookup.valueOf(senderId, "somesenderId"));
        applicationWrapper.setCreatedBy(lookup.valueOf(createdBy, make(a(UserMaker.User))));
        applicationWrapper.setCreatedAt(lookup.valueOf(createdAt, CommonUtils.getMysqlTimeStamp()));
        applicationWrapper.setType(lookup.valueOf(type, make(a(ApplicationTypeMaker.ApplicationType))));
        applicationWrapper.setUpdatedBy(lookup.valueOf(updatedBy, 11));
        applicationWrapper.setOtpLength(lookup.valueOf(otpLength, 6));
        applicationWrapper.setSignature(lookup.valueOf(signature, "some-signature,#OTP"));
        applicationWrapper.setRequestPerIp(lookup.valueOf(requestPerIp, 100));
        applicationWrapper.setSecretKey(lookup.valueOf(secretKey, new JSONArray(make(a(ApplicationSecretKeyMaker.ApplicationSecretKey)))));


      //  System.out.println(applicationWrapper.getSecretKeys().toString());
       // Gson gson = new Gson();
       // System.out.println(gson.toJson(applicationWrapper));
       // System.out.println(new JSONArray(applicationWrapper.getSecretKeys()));
        return applicationWrapper;
       //
    };
```

and this object is given to GSON read and write method

```
public class ApplicationJsonAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ApplicationWrapper> {
  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, ApplicationWrapper application) throws IOException {
    out.beginObject();
    out.name("name").value(application.getName());
    out.name("packageName").value(application.getPackageName());
    out.name("otpExpiry").value(application.getOtpExpiry());
    out.name("type").value(application.getType().getName());
    out.name("key").value(application.getKey());
    out.name("senderId").value(application.getSenderId());
    out.name("otpLength").value(application.getOtpLength());
    out.name("requestPerIp").value(application.getRequestPerIp());
    out.name("secretKey").value(application.getSecretKey().toString());
    out.name("signature").value(application.getSignature());
    out.name("sendOTPInResponse").value(application.getSendOTPInResponse());
    out.endObject();
  }


  @Override
  public ApplicationWrapper read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    ApplicationWrapper application = new ApplicationWrapper();
    JSONArray secretKeys=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    reader.beginObject();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      String name = reader.nextName();
      switch (name) {
        case "type":
          ApplicationType type = new ApplicationType(reader.nextString());
          application.setType(type);
          break;
        case "packageName":
          application.setPackageName(reader.nextString());
          break;
        case "otpExpiry":
          application.setOtpExpiry(reader.nextInt());
          break;
        case "name":
          application.setName(reader.nextString());
          break;
        case "senderId":
          application.setSenderId(reader.nextString());
          break;
        case "otpLength":
          application.setOtpLength(reader.nextInt());
          break;
        case "requestPerIp":
          application.setRequestPerIp(reader.nextLong());
          break;
        case "secretKey":
          reader.beginArray();
          while (reader.hasNext()) {
            secretKeys.put(reader.nextString());
          }
          System.out.println("json adapter" +secretKeys);
          reader.endObject();
          application.setSecretKey(secretKeys);
          break;
        case "signature":
          application.setSignature(reader.nextString());
          break;
        case "sendOTPInResponse":
          application.setSendOTPInResponse(reader.nextInt());
          break;
        default:
          reader.skipValue();
        break;
      }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    return application;
  }
}
```

THis is the problematic line

```
reader.beginArray();
```

EDIT : IT ALL WORKS WHEN I MAKE JSON THROUGH REST CLIENT AND HIT THE API

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: Can you post the code where you use this? A bit more context would be helpful here.

Comment: Please check sir .. if you are not able to get something please ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out.name("secretKey").value(application.getSecretKey().toString());
```

The line above is wrong. You're making it a string rather than an array, thus making your reader to fail. You seem to want:

```
out.name("secretKey")
out.beginArray();
for ( final String s : application.getSecretKey() ) {
    out.value(s);
}
out.endArray();
```

once you throw away `JSONArray` from your `secretKey` property changing it to `String[]` or `List<String>`. Also I strongly recommend you to use data binding rather than streaming for simple cases.

P.S. `JSONArray` does not exist in the Gson realm. + JSON-related stuff should be used only for serialization and deserialization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON

Try: **{**"secretKey" : ["121212","32234324"]**}**

Comment: The OP mentioned a _valid_ JSON. He's asking _how_ it's `secretKey` can be deserialized from a string containing a JSON to a ready-to-use string array.